# inject string at %(variable)s in R (Url pattern)

Tags: string, r, rest, replace, rcurl

I am tryning to build some kind of rest full api to comunicate with R.
Got an issue with replacement of strings.

I've got a url path as:

```
http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/%(id)s/model_function
```

I need to replace "%(id)s" with the model's id. I would like some function like python stuff:

```
function(url, list(id=[id_value])
```

returning...

```
http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/[id_value]/model_function
```

Any tips around? I will implement by string replacement:

```
substitute_url_args <- function(url, list_args){
  replace_names <- paste("%(",names(list_args),")s", sep="")<br>
  i <- 1
  for (i in 1:length(names(list_args))) {
    url <- sub(replace_names[i], list_args[[i]], url, fixed=TRUE)
  }
  return(url)
}
```

Sure this is not an elegant solution!

Thanks in advance,

André

Comment: Use `sprintf` or for more complicated template like functionality look at the `whisker` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `gsubfn` in the gsubfn package:

```
library(gsubfn)

substitute_url_args <- function(url, list_args) {
  gsubfn("%\\((.*?)\\)s", x = url, env = list_args)
}

# test
s <- "http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/%(id)s/model_function"
L <- list(id = "[model_value]")

substitute_url_args(s, L)
## [1] "http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/[model_value]/model_function"
```

**Note** If you are in control of this and can specify that backquotes are to surround the substitutions then its even easier:

```
substitute_url_args2 <- function(url, list_args) {
  gsubfn(x = url, env = list_args)
}

# test - L from above
ss <- "http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/`id`/model_function"

substitute_url_args2(ss, L)
## [1] "http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/[model_value]/model_function"
```

**Note 2** If we knew there were only one variable to replace then it could be done using `sub` like this:

```
substitute_url_args3 <- function(url, list_args) {
  stopifnot(length(list_args) == 1)
  sub("%\\(.*?\\)s", list_args[[1]], url)
}

# test - s and L from above
substitute_url_args3(s, L)
## [1] "http://localhost:8000/rest/api/model/[model_value]/model_function"
```

Comment: Thanks for such fast answer!
I am in a quite hurry these days as soon as I try it out I will let you know.